# Given $n$, how to find integers $a_0,...,a_n$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ has $n$ distinct real roots, and $\max{(|a_0|,...,|a_n|)}$ is minimized?

Tags: polynomials

For a given value of $n$, I want an $n$th degree polynomial with integer coefficients, and $n$ distinct real roots.

But I dislike large coefficients! That is, I want to minimize the value of $\max{(|a_0|,...,|a_n|)}$.

> Given $n$, how to find integers $a_0,...,a_n$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ has $n$ distinct real roots, and $\max{(|a_0|,...,|a_n|)}$ is minimized?

For $n=1$ to $6$, I drew lots of graphs to find a (possibly non-unique) polynomial with $M_n$, the minimum value of $\max{(|a_0|,\dots, |a_n|)}$. But this method takes a very long time for larger values of $n$.

$M_1=1: \space x$
$M_2=1: \space x^2-1$ or $x^2-x$
$M_3=1: \space x^3-x$
$M_4=2: \space x^4-2x^2+x$
$M_5=2: \space x^5-x^4-2x^3+x^2+x$
$M_6=3: \space x^6-x^5-3x^4+2x^3+2x^2-x$

([Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4662090/398708): For given $n$, how to find integers $a_0, ..., a_n$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ has $n$ distinct real roots and $\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|$ is minimized?)

Answer (score 2):

What kind of answer do you expect? Do you want an efficient algorithm which  produces optimal cases for larger degrees? Or do you hope for an explicit family, one polynomial for each degree, whose coefficients are reasonably small?

In the latter case, you may check several families of orthogonal polynomials. In the former case, I guess there is nothing better than a brute force search.

A definite criterion is given by the Sturm sequences. In fact for a given polynomial you need not compute the whole sequence, for if the leading coefficients of two consecutive members (except for the start pair) of the sequence have the same sign, or if the degree drops by more than $1$, then one knows already that there are non-real roots.

So with this algorithm, one finds two more optimal examples in degrees $7$ and $8$. The one in degree $7$ is particularly nice, since its roots are $0,-1,1,\pm\omega,\pm1/\omega$, where the $\omega$ is the golden ratio. So the polynomial is
\begin{equation}
x^7 - 4x^5 + 4x^3 - x=(x^3-x)(x^2 - x - 1)(x^2 + x - 1).
\end{equation}
An optimal degree $8$ example is
\begin{equation}
x^8 + x^7 - 5x^6 - 3x^5 + 6x^4 + 3x^3 - 2x^2 - x=(x^3-x)(x^2 - x - 1)(x^3 + 2x^2 - x - 1).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an efficient algorithm that produces an optimal polynomial for any given degree. I will look into the Sturm sequences.